# Can't clear form/state after input in React.js

Tags: forms, reactjs, state

I have a form which ultimately will be used as the UI to make some API calls to [Open weather map](https://openweathermap.org).

Right now when I submit the a zip code in the input field, upon submission `[object Object]` propagates the field like in the screen shot below.

The call to the API is working as I am getting the JSON for the correct zip code...

But shouldn't this in the `handleSubmit` take care of everything i.e. using `Object.assign` to create new state and then using `form.zipcode.value = '';` to clear out the input?

Thanks in advance!!

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = document.forms.weatherApp;
    api.getWeatherByZip(this.state.zipcode).then(
      function(zip) {
        console.log('zip', zip);

        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            zipcode: Object.assign({}, zip),
          };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
    form.zipcode.value = '';
  }
```

I have enclosed all of the component's code here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import * as api from '../utils/api';

    import '../scss/app.scss';

    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          zipcode: [],
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          zipcode: event.target.value,
        });
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = document.forms.weatherApp;
        api.getWeatherByZip(this.state.zipcode).then(
          function(zip) {
            console.log('zip', zip);

            this.setState(function() {
              return {
                zipcode: Object.assign({}, zip),
              };
            });
          }.bind(this)
        );
        form.zipcode.value = '';
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <form name="weatherApp" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <h2>Open Weather App</h2>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="one-half column">
                  <label htmlFor="insertMode">Insert your location</label>
                  <input
                    name="zipcode"
                    className="u-full-width"
                    placeholder="please enter your zipcode"
                    type="text"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={this.state.zipcode}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="one-half column">
                  <label htmlFor="showMin">show minimum</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                  <label htmlFor="showMax">show maximum</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                  <label htmlFor="showMean">show mean</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="two-half column">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let react manage the changes to the DOM rather that editing it manually. As the value of your input field is already bound to `this.state.zipcode` to reset it just invoke `this.setState({zipcode: ''})` instead of `form.zipcode.value='';`.